# CreateCheckStatusResponse Durable Functions attach Data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Durable Azure Function and I was hoping to add data to the response. Just one field really. I cant seem to find any possible way to do it and this is where I am basically leaving off on code wise. I thought about maybe adding to the request a deliminating character but that just adds to the entirety of the string for the urls.

So my question is: Is there a way for me to append a value to the CreateCheckStatusResponse so that way I can have an Id of the object instead of polling against the url for that response?

```
   string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("SendCorrespondence", request);
                var correspondenceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                req.HttpContext.Items.Add("correspondenceId", correspondenceId);
                req.Headers.Add("correspondenceId", correspondenceId);
                var test = starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId+"."+correspondenceId);
                return test;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add the object id to the URL  in the `HttpStart` Class and the durable client by default polls the URL in the location header  if the function is in `Async` operation.
To add the object id, this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-features?tabs=csharp) may helps you